# Sending sms using API and URL

Tags: vb.net

I am sending an sms from my application but the problem is when the recepient receives the sms the same line of text is repeated. It's duplicating the message, you read the same thing twice in one sms. can someone help?

```vb
     Public Function sendSMS()


        Dim message = rtxtMessage.Text
        Dim number = txtNumber.Text
        Dim strPost As String

        Dim apikey = "Api Key"
        Dim url As String = "URL?recipientNumber=" & number & "&message=" & message & ""

        strPost = url

        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strPost)
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPost)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()

        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        Console.ReadLine()

        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()

        If responseFromServer.Length > 0 Then
            Return responseFromServer
        Else
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: Please include your code that is responsible for sending the SMS.

Comment: @JasonTyler, I added the my code

Comment: I'm surprised you have to put the message text in the url _and_ inside the post content.

Comment: @droopsnoot, Thanks for you help. The problem is now solved

Comment: How did you solve it? Sometimes adding the solution can help other people who might have a similar problem as you did.

Comment: @droopsnoot, I removed the request.contenttype line of code